# Edit Multiple cells at once, in Aggrid - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, celleditorlistener

I am using ag grid react, where I have multiple row selection enabled. I have a cell in the row where the user can add comments on the data displayed. What I am trying to accomplish is instead of user having to type out the same comment on different rows at multiple times, they user could select the checkbox edit one cell and the changes can be populated in the comment cell of the selected rows to enhance UX.
Hence in essence, trying to edit multiple cells at once, using aggrid react.
Any help or suggestions, Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please update your question to add the actual code you are attempting to use so we might help you fixing the ONE issue you struggle with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.